# Очень долгая сборка проекта Google Maps в Android

Tags: android, карты

Здравствуйте!
Такая проблема: создаю Google Maps Activity, получаю API-ключ, вставляю в Манифест, запускаю - в итоге компиляция происходит долго (дольше, чем любые другие приложения).

Может, у кого-то была такая проблема, или я криворукий что-то делаю не так?

На всякий случай код `MapsActivity`, хотя я ничего там не писал:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

Comment: gradle в студию, увеличу скорость по Вашим подключенным библиотекам

Answer (score 0):

Google Map тянет за собой зависимости. При чем большие. А как всем известно чем больше зависимостей, тем дольше будет собираться проект. Можно ускорить сборку как показано в [этой статье](https://medium.com/google-developers/faster-android-studio-builds-with-dex-in-process-5988ed8aa37e#.otu1a95fn). Но это не относится никак к картам